# How can I configure Flutter to use two different APIs?

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter app and I would like to call multiple API endpoints which use different databases.

I don't know if I should do this on the backend or the frontend.

**api1.php:**

```
<?php // header('Content-Type: application/json');
include "config.php";$sql = "select inventeries.pic_inv,inventeries.name,site.Sname,users.number from inventeries,site,users";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$med = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($med);
?>
```

**api_2.php:**

```
<?php
// header('Content-Type: application/json');
include "config.php";
$sql = "select users.pic_inv,users.name,site.Sname,users.number from users,site,users";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$med = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($med);
?>
```

Currently they use the same database, so the results from both APIs are the same:

```
{"pic_inv":"ACICAL-PLUS.jpg","name":"Aclcal","Sname":"flowers pharma","number":"7894561231"}
{"pic_inv":"ACICAL-PLUS.jpg","name":"Aclcal","Sname":"flowers pharma","number":"123456789"}
{"pic_inv":"what-a-treatment-for-migraine-headache.jpg","name":"foar","Sname":"flowers pharma","number":"7894561231"}
{"pic_inv":"what-a-treatment-for-migraine-headache.jpg","name":"foar","Sname":"flowers pharma","number":"123456789"}
{"pic_inv":"syrunj.png","name":"AMLO","Sname":"flowers pharma","number":"7894561231"}
{"pic_inv":"syrunj.png","name":"AMLO","Sname":"flowers pharma","number":"123456789"}
{"pic_inv":"cap.jpg","name":"pandol","Sname":"flowers pharma","number":"7894561231"}
{"pic_inv":"cap.jpg","name":"pandol","Sname":"flowers pharma","number":"123456789"}
```

Comment: Its probably easier for you if the API will handle this part.. have the API fetch from both the databases, filter the data however you want and return that as json

Comment: how ?
i used curl but no result
is there any way to handle APIs from both databases

Comment: im not familiar with php, but im sure there are ways to do it.. if not, are there endpoints in the api to make the requests to access the databases individually?

Comment: yah , 
that's the code i used , ,,,,,,,,,,,,

    include "config.php";

    $sql = "select inventeries.pic_inv,inventeries.name,site.Sname,users.number from inventeries,site,users";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $med = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($med);

Comment: i am writing an answer for you, can you post the json responses from both of the database endpoints?

Comment: @Danny look at the results

Comment: so both databases are the same with the same tables.. just different data.. and you want the data to be mixed from both and returned to you?

Comment: @Danny yes :) i hope got the awnser

Comment: in case you're doing it in the backend, what's the point in having two databases? It just makes no sense, if you're calling a single API but for some reason it would connect to two different databases

Comment: @YourCommonSense Why not? That would make it a data-aggregator API of sorts. You could have, for example, one database strictly for user- and application data and one for your bigger datamasses.

Comment: @Swiffy because that's not how databases work

Comment: @YourCommonSense there are some systems that are infrastructured in a way to make users of the system in one database, and the data in another..

Answer (score 0):

Well, as i have said, i have no experience with PHP and all would be easier in the API..

but you can make a model in your flutter app like lets say the data you get from **DB1 endpoint** is like this

```
{   
    "inventeries.pic_inv" : "something",
    "inventeries.name" : "something",
    "site.Sname" : "something",
    "users.number" : "something"
}
```

and the data you get from **DB2 Endpoint** is like this

```
{   
    "users.pic_inv" : "something",
    "users.name" : "something",
    "site.Sname" : "something",
    "users.number" : "something"
}
```

then you prepare a model that combines all to be something like this.. lets call it **MixedModel**

```
{   
    //Mixed both data and get only the data you want..
    "users.pic_inv" : "something",
    "users.name" : "something",
    "inventeries.pic_inv" : "something",
    "inventeries.name" : "something"
    "site.Sname" : "something",
    "users.number" : "something",
}
```

you can use https://app.quicktype.io/ to generate the models for your data.

then you can make a function that can make a call to both of the endpoints
im using **[Dio Package](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)** to make the API Calls..

```
Future<List<MixedModel>> GetDataFromADatabase() async {
  try{
    String URL_ENDPOINT_ONE = "URL TO ENDPOINT 1";
    String URL_ENDPOINT_TWO = "URL TO ENDPOINT 2";

    var ResponseOne = await Dio().get(URL_ENDPOINT_ONE);
    var ResponseTwo = await Dio().get(URL_ENDPOINT_TWO);

    if(ResponseOne.statusCode == 200 && ResponseTwo.statusCode == 200){
      // only if both requests are successful
      var data = jsonDecode(ResponseOne.data.toString()) as List<MixedModel>;
//combine data
      data.addAll(json.decode(ResponseTwo.data.toString()) as List<MixedModel>);
      return data;
      
    }
    List<MixedModel> empty = [];
    return empty;
  }
  catch (ex){
    List<MixedModel> empty = [];
    
    if(ex is dio.DioError){
      print( ex.response);
    }
    return empty;
  }
}
```

I hope you get the idea